# Download Speed Rate Drops to 0 kb/s after 2 seconds!

Tags: networking, xubuntu, 19.04, wget, download-speed

this is ridiculous but my download speed drops to 0 kb/s after downloading about 200KB of a file...
 I've tested my network with other devices and it's fine but I still can't download with my laptop. can anyone help me where should I look for the issue?

the funniest thing is that I can browse web pages without any problem!

ps: my OS is `ubuntu 19.04`

ps2: I've tried downloading files with `composer` , `wget` , `chrome` , `firefox` and `opera` and got the same result!

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 06 Sep 2019 10:02 +0430 +0430

Booted last: 06 Sep 2019 00:00 +0430 +0430

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.0.0-27-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 20 19:53:07 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

ubuntu-wayland

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1503] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [103c:161d]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

24:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (802.11a/b/g/n) [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0003 SiGma Micro HID controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-BlueTooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

##### lsmod #############################

iwldvm                233472  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mac80211              806912  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               311296  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              671744  3 iwldvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
wmi                    28672  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp0s25' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 49352sec preferred_lft 49352sec
    inet6 fe80::7d5b:87cd:d5cb:6910/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Rahmat"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]>   
          Bit Rate=39 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:1641   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search Home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      5069     1  0 Sep05 ?        00:00:10 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (802.11a/b/g/n))
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.0.0-27-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               18.168.6.1
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:24:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlo1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Rahmat
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       9e308d55-29ee-41c3-8414-2e507a7ff5cc
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     39 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.2/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          Home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dad_wait_time = 0
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        domain_name = Home
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        expiry = 1567797282
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.2
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::7d5b:87cd:d5cb:6910/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/5,/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/6,/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/12
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   fe13834f-faac-4fee-a73a-1d422584fb63 | aabadi
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   64fa79b7-1494-4d09-8107-7436632ec0e1 | abadi
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[3]:   9e308d55-29ee-41c3-8414-2e507a7ff5cc | Rahmat

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s25
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        82579V Gigabit Network Connection
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.13-4
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s25' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/enp0s25
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID    BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 
Rahmat  <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  130 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1      yes     *      

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/pasavan.ir]] (600 root)
[connection] id=pasavan.ir | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=pasavan.ir
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Rahmat.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Rahmat | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Rahmat
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Soheil bridge]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Soheil bridge | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Soheil bridge
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ECollegeMe]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ECollegeMe | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ECollegeMe
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/aabadi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=aabadi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=aabadi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/S.rahmat_]] (600 root)
[connection] id=S.rahmat | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=S.rahmat
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/IDS]] (600 root)
[connection] id=IDS | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=IDS
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MobinNet0104]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MobinNet0104 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MobinNet0104
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Pasavan.ir]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Pasavan.ir | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Pasavan.ir
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/abadi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=abadi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=abadi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HWFIG-H]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HWFIG-H | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=HWFIG-H
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TP-LINK_9EB493]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TP-LINK_9EB493 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TP-LINK_9EB493
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Tehran (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp0s25   no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlo1      32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp0s25   Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlo1      Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy

##### module infos ######################

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     C1AECE727ECF35F7B64093C
depends:        mac80211,iwlwifi,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwldvm
vermagic:       5.0.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
signature:      ...
parm:           force_cam:force continuously aware mode (no power saving at all) (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     E72AE83255B6276A3F26D2D
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.0.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
signature: ...     
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-a0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-su-z0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-hr-a0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-jf-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-f0-hr-a0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0-43.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0-43.ucode
srcversion:     5C219507EA35BD8380956D4
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.0.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
signature: ...     
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for 22560 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 0 (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     8F0CAF5346FF71FCE9CB198
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.0.0-27-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
signature:...   
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwldvm]
force_cam: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
d0i3_timeout: 1000
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
enable_ini: N
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    5.590988] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[    6.431376] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[    8.242233] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0 (repeated 2 times)
[   11.934495] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]>
[   11.936531] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[   11.939292] wlo1: authenticated
[   11.939478] wlo1: waiting for beacon from <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]>
[   12.033927] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[   12.037278] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   12.039294] wlo1: associated
[   13.077220] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[  400.118042] wlo1: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  403.595354] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]>
[  403.596920] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[  403.599880] wlo1: authenticated
[  403.607280] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[  403.610665] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  403.612742] wlo1: associated
[  403.651379] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[  407.470764] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Down
[  407.544575] wlo1: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  409.465115] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0 (repeated 2 times)
[  413.102843] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]>
[  413.103864] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[  413.106738] wlo1: authenticated
[  413.110018] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[  413.113373] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  413.116506] wlo1: associated
[  413.152441] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[  554.048927] wlo1: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  554.056231] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]>
[  554.057243] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[  554.059991] wlo1: authenticated
[  554.061909] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[  554.065386] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Rahmat' [AN1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  554.068309] wlo1: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Type of connection? Wifi? Ethernet? Ethernet over PLC? Tried another type? Dowloading to where? HDD? SSD? RAM? Individual components of a web page are usually under 200KB.

Comment: os is installed on ssd. tried over wifi & ethernet and also downloading to HDD and SSD! sill same result!

Comment: Has this always been the case?  If no: What changed? If yes, [Go here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos), [edit] your question and give us a bit more information...

Comment: Do you have QoS enabled in your router? Are you using a VPN? Have you rebooted your router/modem/etc?

Comment: @Fabby. No this wasn't always the case. And I have no clue what changed! I just realized it when I was trying to download some files with `wget`! I've provided the information you've asked!

Comment: @heynnema. I've reset my router settings but I'm sure it's about my operating system because all other devices and my windows 8 inside the same device is working well.

Comment: Try turning off IPV6, because I can't see anything wrong with your settings...